# Error: Style property 'width' is not supported by native animated module

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, animation, expo

I'd like to create this animation:

[image]

And here's my code:

```js
import React, { FC, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Animated, StyleSheet, View, Easing } from 'react-native';

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  circle: {
    borderWidth: 2,
    borderColor: 'black',
    position: 'absolute',
  },
  container: {
    width: 100,
    height: 100,
    position: 'relative',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});

const createSequence = (animation: Animated.Value, from: number, to: number) => Animated.sequence([
  Animated.timing(animation, {
    toValue: from,
    duration: 0,
    useNativeDriver: true,
  }),
  Animated.timing(animation, {
    toValue: to,
    duration: 1000,
    easing: Easing.linear,
    useNativeDriver: true,
  }),
]);

const SpinnerCircle: FC<{ delay: number, color: string }> = ({ delay, color }) => {
  const radius = new Animated.Value(35);
  const opacity = new Animated.Value(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    Animated.sequence([
      Animated.delay(delay),
      Animated.loop(
        Animated.parallel([
          createSequence(radius, 0, 100),
          createSequence(opacity, 1, 0),
        ]),
        { iterations: -1 },
      ),
    ]).start();
  }, []);

  return (
    <Animated.View style={[styles.circle, {
      width: radius,
      height: radius,
      borderRadius: radius,
      borderColor: color,
      opacity,
    }]}/>
  );
};

export const Spinner: FC = () => (
  <View style={styles.container}>
    <SpinnerCircle delay={0} color="#2626CC"/>
    <SpinnerCircle delay={500} color="#E0E0E0"/>
  </View>
);
```

The code DO work well in the web version. But when I'm trying to run it in android emulator, where's an error: **Error: Style property 'width' is not supported by native animated module**

How can I deal with it?

I know, I could use `transform` and `scale`. But `scale` also scales border width, which is required to be the same size.

Comment: set `useNativeDriver` to `false`

Comment: not working bro